# How to validate if a folder already exists

Tags: c#, validation, file-exists

I want to create folders and add classes within the folders. I can create the folder once, but once I have created it, I just want to add classes. My code gives error because I'm trying to create a folder several times, which is not right. So before adding a class to the folder, I want to check if the folder already exists and if it exists I just want to add the class.

```
 ProjectItem rootFolder = project.ProjectItems.AddFolder(folder);                    
 ProjectItem item = rootFolder.ProjectItems.AddFromTemplate(itemPath, className);
```

Comment: Folders are `ProjectItem` too, what does [the documentation say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.projectitems?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)? as far as I can see there is no `Exists` method, but you can enumerate (actually: traverse) the items and test each one for equality with your folder.

Comment: related: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/95b3b912-d368-45d5-a1c1-4d1c22891b8a/how-to-determine-if-a-visual-studio-project-alrady-contains-a-projectitem?forum=vsx

Comment: Yes and `folder` is a string. I have a `for each`, for each class i create a folder. but if i have two classes that belong to the same folder give me error because I am not doing this validation. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: based on the comment discussions below the existing answers, for clarification, `ProjectItems.AddFolder` creates a **solution folder**. is that what you want or are you talking about the normal "physical" directory structure on disk?

Comment: creates a solution folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.projectitems.addfolder?view=visualstudiosdk-2017), there is no kind of `Exists` function which would tell us if a folder already existed.

So you have at least two options:

**1. Try and ignore**

Simply:

```
try 
{
    var rootFolder = project.ProjectItems.AddFolder(folder);
}
catch 
{
    /* folder already exists, nothing to do */
}
```

**2. Solution folders can only occur in the first level below the solution root node, so we can get away with a non-recursive solution.**

```
public static bool CheckIfSolutionFolderExists(ProjectItems projectItems, string foldername)
{
    foreach(var projectItem in projectItems)
    {
        if(projectItem.Kind == EnvDTE.vsProjectItemKindVirtualFolder)
        {
            if(projectItem.Name == foldername)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

For a recursive solution, I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.projectitems.addfolder?view=visualstudiosdk-2017), which boils down to:

```
public static bool CheckIfFileExistsInProject(ProjectItems projectItems, string fullpath)
{
    foreach(ProjectItem projectItem in projectItems)
    {
        if(projectItem.Name == fullpath)
        {
            return true; 
        }
        else if ((projectItem.ProjectItems != null) && (projectItem.ProjectItems.Count > 0))
        {
            /* recursive search */
            return CheckIfFileExistsInProject(projectItem.ProjectItems, fullpath);
        }
    } 
    return false;
}
```

A robust pattern for solution and project folder management would use `AddFromDirectory` whenever you want to mirror the file system hierarchy in the project tree, and `AddFolder` only for virtual folders that have no representation in the file system.

```
ProjectItem item;
if(Directory.Exists(itemname))
{
    item = project.AddFromDirectory(itemname);
}
else
{
    item = project.AddFolder(itemname);
}
```

(source: inspired from [this](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/ProjectItems/AddFolder/php-projectitems-addfolder-method-examples.html))

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `Directory.Exists`

and in your code it'll be look like there

```
if(!Directory.Exists(folder)) { 
  ProjectItem rootFolder = project.ProjectItems.AddFolder(folder);
}
ProjectItem item = rootFolder.ProjectItems.AddFromTemplate(itemPath, className);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

```
if(Directory.Exists(path)) 
{
    // The folder already exists
}
else 
{
    //Create a new folder here ...
}
```

Please check this out for more details on [Directory.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: how does that relate to the question? OP want to prevent adding folders to the solution tree that have already been previously added.

Comment: This code sample basically for checks whether a folder exists or not, isn't this the problem faced by the OP? If the folder already exists than proceed to add items to it, else create a new one.

Comment: I think not, because `ProjectItem.AddFolder` unlike `ProjectItem.AddFromDirectory` does not take a physical path - its just the name of the folder node in solution explorer. this kind of folder lives in the sln file as a `Project` entry, but does not correspond to a directory on disk.